# Discrete wavelet transform - DWT (beginner)

Tags: python, forecasting, references, finance, wavelet

I recently stumbled upon [this article](https://www.bportugal.pt/sites/default/files/anexos/papers/wp201612_0.pdf).
In the paper they use DWT and I am having trouble understanding how to construct them. Does anyone have a guide on where to start learning wavelets and slowly move to DWT? I am a beginner in this part so I am really trying to understand from step 0. I will apply the math in python.

I have checked the others threads and the questions are to specific, so let's try to answer this question so that it can become a guide for future reference.